# Insert Excel range below text in body of email

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to create an email which has a range of cells inserted from Excel, directly below a body field (of string/html).

The `.Body` overrides the Excel range in the drafted email.

```vb
Sub TryExcel()
    Dim myXL As Excel.Application 'Early bind - needs a reference to Excel
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook 'Early bind - needs a reference to Excel
    Dim myMail As MailItem

   
    Set myXL = GetObject(, "Excel.Application") 'Excel already running
    Set wb = myXL.Workbooks("Sheet1.xlsm") '<-- Wb already open. Rename as appropriate
  
    wb.RefreshAll
    wb.Worksheets("1").Range("A1:d4").Copy '<-- adjust your range as appropriate
    Set myMail = ThisOutlookSession.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    With myMail
        .Display
        .GetInspector.WordEditor.Range.Paste 'Asumes Word as email editor
        .To = "*******.com"
        .Importance = olImportanceHigh
        .Subject = "<type the subject of your email here>"
        .Body = "<type the email message text here>"
        .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
 
        '.Send
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Body](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.body) property sets a string representing the clear-text body of the Outlook item. Instead, I'd recommend using the [HTMLBody](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.htmlbody) property which allows preserving the existing formatting if any.

In case of dealing with HTML based message bodies you need to find the `<body>` tag and insert your content right after it. So, the pasted content from Excel will not be modified.

Answer (score 0):

To not overwrite existing values. `x = x + y`

In this case the order matters. `x = y + x`

```
.body = "<type the email message text here>" & vbCrLf & .body
```